# Laptop shutdowns when battery low instead of suspend

Tags: 14.04, power-management, battery

My Ubuntu 14.04 laptop has started to shut down when the battery is low even though I have set it to suspend when power is critically low. It has also stopped showing me power low notifications even though I have it enabled. How to fix this?

Comment: What does `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action` tell you ? Please run that command in terminal

Comment: it returned `'interactive'`

Comment: OK, so that's the wrong value. Do `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'suspend'` , see if that has any effect. Likely case is that what you do in System Settings  GUI doesn't actually take effect in the settings database.

Comment: Thanks! can you also on to make my Bluetooth work again? I think it's because of package conflicts because at fresh install it worked. any idea how to restore it to working condition?

Comment: So did that work or not ? As for bluetooth, I don't know much about it, and it's not related to this question, so you might wanna post a new question about it, and maybe someone who knows about bluetooth more than I do can help

Comment: Thanks! didn't check it as my laptop battery is above 50% rn. Will post if it works when the battery goes low.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54692/discussion-between-shahzaib-rahim-and-serg).